# How to show that a Telegram Channel post was read

Tags: telegram-bot, telethon

I'm trying to use Telethon to pull Telegram channel posts but have it captured as a true view event. Right now, I can successfully use my client (snipped below) to pull all the posts from the channel, but, afterwards when I look at the post on my phone I don't see a reflection of that client action. Welcome help on how I can do read messages and have it reflected as a read event in the post stats. Here is the function that I am using.

```
def messages(api_id, api_hash, phone, channel):
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
    client.connect()
    for message in client.iter_messages(channel, reverse=True):
        print(message)
    client.disconnect()
```

Again, this function works in pulling all the posts, but does not show as being read when looking at the posts stats, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You may either use [send_read_acknowledge](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.send_read_acknowledge) or [mark_read](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.mark_read) to double-check a message.

You can edit your code like this:

```
def messages(api_id, api_hash, phone, channel):
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
    client.connect()
    for message in client.iter_messages(channel, reverse=True):
        print(message)
        message.mark_read()
    client.disconnect()
```